# Create a list that its elements are grouped by type

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
lst =  [4,67,8, 'not found', 32, 'missing', 21, 23, 'warning', 'alert', 2.01, [], {}]
```

I want to create a new list that is grouped by its type. For example i want my list to be

```
new =  [4,67,8, 32, 21, 23, 2.01,'not found','missing','warning', 'alert', [], {}]
```

As we checked from the code below we find the types of each element and assign that to a set to be unique

```
type_list = []
for i in lst:
    type_list.append(type(i))

type_set = set(type_list)
```

The type_set returned this {int, float, str, list, dict}
Now i want to group the list above by per type in the type_set as shown above:

```
new =  [4,67,8, 32, 21, 23, 2.01,'not found','missing','warning', 'alert', [], {}]

for index, data_type in enumerate(list(type_set)):
  tel = list(filter(lambda x : (index, data_type), lst))
print(tel)
```

Of course it didnt print something. How to achieve it without using sorted?

Comment: why do you need that fixed order `{int, float, str, list, dict}` ?

Comment: Why without sorted?

Comment: *"Of course it didnt print something"* - It did when I tried it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used a group-by + flattening approach:

```
lst =  [4,67,8, 'not found', 32, 'missing', 21, 23, 'warning', 'alert', 2.01, [], {}]

# form groups
groups_types = {}
for v in lst:
    groups_types.setdefault(type(v).__name__, []).append(v)

# flat
new = []
for grp in groups_types.values():
    new.extend(grp)

print(new)
```

Remark: the type name and the object `type` are both unique and can be used as keys. I choose for the type name using the `__name__` attribute, for the other case is enough to remove this attribute.

---

Trying to fix the OP's mistake: create a mask for each `type` and apply it repeatedly to the original list. You can use [itertools.compress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) (in the doc there is a standard library implementation) to apply the mask to the list.

```
import itertools as it


lst =  [4,67,8, 'not found', 32, 'missing', 21, 23, 'warning', 'alert', 2.01, [], {}]

# form groups
groups_types = {}
for v in lst:
    groups_types.setdefault(type(v).__name__, []).append(v)


# mask & filter
for data_type in groups_types:
    mask = (type(term).__name__ == data_type for term in lst)
    lst_filtered = it.compress(lst, mask)
    print(*lst_filtered, end=' ')
else:
    print() # just for proper formatting
```

Answer (score 0):

A *type* is hashable and can therefore be used as a key in a dictionary.

Therefore:

```
lst = [4, 67, 8, "not found", 32, "missing", 21, 23, "warning", "alert", 2.01, [], {}]

d = {t: [] for t in (int, float, str, list, dict)}

for e in lst:
    d[type(e)].append(e)

new = []

for v in d.values():
    new += v

print(new)
```

**Output:**

```
[4, 67, 8, 32, 21, 23, 2.01, 'not found', 'missing', 'warning', 'alert', [], {}]
```

Comment: Respect the variable names as suggested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

With a custom [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) (which is guaranteed to be [stable](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts)):

```
order = [int, float, str, list, dict]

out = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: order.index(type(x)))
```

Output :

```
[
    4,             # ints
    67,
    8,
    32,
    21,
    23,
    2.01,          # floats
    'not found',   # strs
    'missing',
    'warning',
    'alert',
    [],            # lists
    {}             # dicts
]
```

Comment: **NB**: This assumes that `lst` doesn't hold objects with different types than `order`.

Answer (score -1):

This code organizes the elements in the original list lst based on their types in the specified order in `type_set`, resulting in a new list called `new`.

```py
lst = [4, 67, 8, 'not found', 32, 'missing', 21, 23, 'warning', 'alert', 2.01, [], {}]
type_set = [int, float, str, list, dict] #the order you want
new = []
for data_type in type_set:
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, data_type):
            new.append(x)
print(new)
#[4, 67, 8, 32, 21, 23, 2.01, 'not found', 'missing', 'warning', 'alert', [], {}]
```